# Dask Dataframe read_sql_table & to_sql method throwing TypeError - Provided index column is of type "object"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, dask, dask-dataframe

Problem/Context: The problem i am facing is i am trying to insert the dask dataframe to postgres db but it seems i am going through bad luck. I tried almost 20-30 times by changing param also different methods and still the same error I am getting. This is might feel similar but it isn't.

> **Error:** *TypeError: Provided index column is of type "object".  If divisions is not provided the index column type must be numeric or datetime. OR  cannot process UnicodeResultProcessor objects *

Some function help to get started:

1. This will help in creating the table in postgres

   ```
   def create_table(db, table):
   """
   Function to create table if not exist
   """
   try:
       conn = psycopg2.connect('postgresql://postgres:root@localhost:5432/dask_ml_table')
   except:
       print("Unable to connect to the database!") 
   cur = conn.cursor()
   if table == "one_table":
       try:
           cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE one_table (date date,Sales integer,X_1 integer,X_2 integer,X_3 integer,X_4 integer,X_5 integer);""")
       except Exception as e:
           print(e)
   conn.commit()
   conn.close()
   cur.close()
   ```

   #Call Fn
   create_table('dask_ml_table','one_table')

2. This will help in creating dataframe to insert

   ```
    from faker import Faker
    from dask.dataframe import from_pandas
    import pandas as pd
    import random
    fake = Faker()
    def create_rows_faker(num=1):
         output = [{"X_5":fake.name(),
                   "X_4":fake.address(),
                   "X_3":fake.email(),
                   #"bs":fake.bs(),
                   "X_2":fake.city(),
                   "X_1":fake.state(),
                   "date":fake.date_time(),
                   #"paragraph":fake.paragraph(),
                   #"Conrad":fake.catch_phrase(),
                   "Sales":random.randint(1000,2000)} for x in range(num)]
         return output
   df_faker = pd.DataFrame(create_rows_faker(1000))
   ddf = from_pandas(df_faker, npartitions=1)
   ```

**Action Plan:**

1. **Insert the above generated dataframe to postgres db**
2. **Fetch all rows back in dask dataframe**

My Approach:

i) First Write

```
ddf.to_sql('one_table',uri='postgresql://postgres:root@localhost/dask_ml_test',
if_exists='append',method='multi',index=False )
dataframe.compute()

Error: TypeError: can't pickle sqlalchemy.cprocessors.UnicodeResultProcessor objects
```

ii) Read

```
username = 'postgres'
password = 'XXXX'
server = 'localhost'
database = 'dask_ml_table'
connection_string = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{server}/{database}'
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
metadata = MetaData()
t = Table('one_table', metadata,
    Column('date'))
sel = select([t]).limit(5).alias('foo')
dd.read_sql_table(sel, connection_string, index_col='date')

Error: TypeError: Provided index column is of type "object".  If divisions is not provided the index column type must be numeric or datetime
```

iii) 2nd Read

```
ndf = dd.read_sql_table("select * from one_table", "postgresql://postgres:root@localhost:5432/dask_ml_table", 'date', npartitions=1)

Error: Table not found
```

Please Help, Need help in both inserting and reading data from dask only. I know it might feel similar, but i have tried to find majority of solution from SOF only, but hardly any worked.